# What is the element of unity for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt5]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What is the element of unity for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt5]$?

Note that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt5\right]=\{a+b\sqrt5\mid a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

I believe that I need to find an element $x$ such that $(a+b\sqrt5)x=a+b\sqrt5$, but I'm struggling to find one. Am I on the right track?

Comment: What about $1$?

Comment: I tried $(a+b\sqrt5)(1+1\sqrt5)$, but that didn't work. Can I use 1 alone, and simply have $b=0$?

Comment: The last time I checked, $0\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $1=1+0\times\sqrt{5}$, we have $1\in\Bbb Z[\sqrt{5}]$.